# What does "synchronise the UIState" mean in the docs for SetParent?

Tags: winapi, user32

The documentation for user32.dll's [`SetParent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541(v=vs.85).aspx) function states that

> When you change the parent of a window, you should synchronize the UISTATE of both windows. For more information, see [WM_CHANGEUISTATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646342(v=vs.85).aspx) and [WM_UPDATEUISTATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646361(v=vs.85).aspx).

I've looked through those pages, and the character sequence *sync* doesn't appear at all. My best guess is that I'm meant to send a `WM_UPDATEUISTATE` message to the new parent window, but I have no idea what parameters to use.

- If it should be a `UIS_INITIALIZE` then I take the second paragraph of the remarks to indicate that the message might be discarded, so I don't have any confidence that it will guarantee synchronisation of state between the parent and the child.
- If it should be two messages, one with `UIS_CLEAR` and the other with `UIS_SET`, then I can't understand why the `SetParent` documentation doesn't also mention `WM_QUERYUISTATE`, so this option doesn't convince me either.

What is the correct interpretation of "*synchronize the UISTATE*"?

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter. It's your decision how your app will work.
You can clear both, or take one state and set the same for the other window, or you can query the last input method mouse/keyboard and hide if mouse, show if keyboard.